# Why isn't my path updating with the components I added?

Tags: terminal, path, solana

I have been trying to install the Solana tool suite on my M1 pro MacBook Pro and have kept running into the same issue no matter how I do it. Basically when I install the Solana tool suite using sudo and add it to my path it works in the current terminal instance. When I type echo $PATH it shows up but when I close the terminal and try doing the same in the new instance I first of all, get zsh : command not found : solana and when running echo $PATH, the Solana CLI isn't there anymore for some reason. I'm pretty new to Mac so some help would be useful...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seemed to solve the problem for me"

Don't give :$PATH at the end during adding the variable, rather add it first

```
# in ~/zshrc
export PATH=$PATH:<my_solana_path>
# omit ":$PATH" after it
```

Answer (score 0):

Include the command used to add the path in your `~/.zshrc` file

Comment: Doesn't work I've tried that already

Answer (score 0):

To add your path globally, type this command `open ~/.zshrc` and paste the path and save the file. This would show the path even after restarting the terminal.

```sh
# in ~/.zshrc
export PATH=<my_solana_path>:$PATH
```

Then either open a new terminal or in a new terminal `source ~/.zshrc`